# Why this UITableViewController doesn't show anything?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, debugging, crash

I'm using the latest beta of Xcode 7. I'm programming a simple UITableView, but this doesn't work well, the inspector error doesn't show anithing but when I start the simulator, the App crash. Can someone help me?

```
    //  RestaurantTableViewController.swift

import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso","Upstate","Traif","Graham Avenue Meats","Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Rpyal Oak", "Thai Cafe"]


    var restaurantImages = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafeloisl.jpg",
        "petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg", "posatelier.jpg", "bourkestreetbakery.jpg",
        "haighschocolate.jpg", "palominoespresso.jpg", "upstate.jpg", "traif.jpg",
        "grahamavenuemeats.jpg", "wafflewolf.jpg", "fiveleaves.jpg", "cafelore.jpg",
        "confessional.jpg", "barrafina.jpg", "donostia.jpg", "royaloak.jpg", "thaicafe.jpg"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.restaurantNames.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...


        cell.textLabel!.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])

    return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: did you select the class for your custom cell in the storyboard sense ? you should cast your `cell` variable to your *custom UITableViewCell* class

Comment: Yes. It's a basic Cell, with the identifier cell. I upload some images in the xcassetes folder. I don't know why the table view doesn't show anything.

Comment: you need to cast your cell to the actual *custom UITableViewCell class* like this: `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? YourClassGoesHere`, don't forget to set the class of the cell in the storyboard sense. If it helps, show me a pic of your attribute inspector for the cell in your sense

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I revise the Cell identifier, and the problem was this, i put Zell in the identifier nit Cell.

Comment: if you solved your problem yourself, kindly write an answer, or delete the question. Happy coding

Comment: Hello, Now I have other error. When I pass data (Image) to other view using a Segue and his method the app stop running and the Debug are says: Could not cast value of type "UIViewController" to "FoodPinTwo.DetailViewController.'

Comment: can you show me more code? I can help, I just need the context